# Get actual line number (or filename) for database error in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

When there is an error with your sql statement in codeigniter you get a message a bit like this:-

```
 A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1096

- some sql -

Filename: \system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 334
```

Which is all well and good but when you've got lots of statements running for a single page it would help to know which line of code generated the query.

How do I get name of the `model` and `method` (or the filename) which generated the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here because I found a quick and dirty solution which works for debugging purposes. I highly recommend leaving CI system files in tact, this should only be used for debugging. I might write an extension for CI to do this when I've got time.

**Solution for CI 2:-**

Go and edit `system\database\DB_driver.php` and add the following code on `line 321`:-

```
echo "<pre>";
debug_print_backtrace();
echo "</pre>";
```